# Program using for loop and EOF gives incorrect character count

Tags: c

(FIXED)

MY ORIGINAL QUESTION (made few mistakes while framing the question) -

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{   
    for (double nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc)
    printf("%0.f", nc);
    return 0;
}
```

if i give input "a" (Exclude quotes), i get 01 as the output,
Input: "ab", output: 012
Input: Return Key, Output: 0

Why is this happening? **Shouldn't \n give output 1**, as in my device the EOF value is -1 and ascii new line character value is 10, I am using VS code and Mac M1, FYI, same output even in online compiler.

I WROTE A WRONG VERSION OF WHAT I WANTED TO ASK

This is the original code from K&R:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{   
    double nc;
    for (nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc)
        ;
    printf("%0.f", nc);
    return 0;
}
```

**I made a mistake with the semi-colons and assumed that for empty `for` loop we don't need a semi-colons and i declared double inside the loop which was not ANSI standard, it messed up the question solvers interpretation, sorry for that.**

Comment: 1) Please fix your indentation. 2) The initial value of nc is 0. And why a double rather than an int? Entry: `a\n` Output: 0 for `a`, 1 for `\n` - Entry: `bc\n` Output: 0 for b, 1 for c, 2 for \n - Entry: `\n` Output: 0 for `\n`. If you are counting from 0, the first number should not be 1.

Comment: 1) Maybe you misunderstood it
```for (double nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc);
    printf("%0.f", nc);```
No need for indentation right?
2) its an example from book, author used it just for the sake of large number compatability...

Comment: The loop will always start counting at `0`. Therefore, there is no reason to expect the first character to be a `1`, irrespective of the number of characters the user enters.

Comment: If the line with the `for` statement had a `;` at the end, then your identation would be correct. However, it does not have a `;` at the end.

Comment: Look again. The code in your comment is not the code in your post. The code in your post produces a counting sequence starting from 0. The code in your comment would not compile as nc is scoped to the loop so the nc in the printf would be an undeclared identifier.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel while your point of the indentation may be valid for styling, the code will work similarly independently of indentation.

Comment: After your most recent edit, the identation is now correct, but your code does not compile, because you are using the variable `nc` outside the [scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/scope) of its declaration. The declaration of `nc` is only valid inside the `for` loop.

Comment: @carylex And you just learned **why** empty loops with that format are **REALLY REALLY BAD CODE**.  You messed it up with a mere three-line program.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the line `for (double nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc);` is written like that in K&R, because declaring a variable inside a `for` statement is only permissible since C99 (which was published in the year 1999). The final edition of the K&R book was published in 1988.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel You are right, its declared outside the for in the book, but while trying to figure out my original problem, i was hit and trialing by changing the double...

Comment: By adding the `;` in your question you've hidden the error and made the question meaningless. The code doesn't match the described output now.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: That used to compile like so long ago. The scope rules were once different and `nc` was still in scope (or was it a compiler bug?). My copy of K&R runs differently though and has `nc` declared on its own line outside the `for` loop.

Comment: @interjay Yeah, now i edited the question to same as the book

Comment: @carylex: Compiling without the `;` worked, but had a completely different meaning. Using `for` causes the program to loop on the next statement. By putting `;` immediately after the closing parenthesis of the `for`, you loop on an empty statement. If you omit the `;`, then you instead loop on the `printf("%0.f", nc);` statement.

Comment: In your question, you write: `"if i give input "a" (Exclude quotes), i get 01 as the output, Input: "ab", output: 012"` -- I believe that this may have been correct for the previous version of your posted code (the one without the `;`), but I don't think it is correct for the current version of your posted code. Please verify that your posted code still corresponds to your posted output, and if not, please correct it.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Yeah, i noticed it now, now my ```printf()``` will never get executed unless i get ```getchar()``` to be equal to ```EOF```, so empty for loops are useless??

Comment: @carylex: Empty loops can be useful in some situations, especially in cases in which evaluating the loop condition has a side effect. I have used empty loops sometimes (but not often). For example, to count the number of lines in a file, you can write: `for (int i=0; fgets(line,sizeof line,fp) != NULL; i++);`

Answer (score 1):

You are looping a variable starting from 0 and you always increment it on each iteration of your loop until `EOF`.

Hence, your output will look like

**012345678910...**

If you just want to get the number of characters prior to EOL, then you can do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{   
    double nc = 0;
    for (nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc);
    printf("%0.f", nc);
    return 0;
}
```

The empty `for` cycle in this case will not contain your `printf`, hence, you will only print the result once, after the end of the loop. With your code the `for` cycle calls `printf` at each step, typing the number of characters so far.

Answer (score 1):

In C, the execution order of a for-loop is as follows:

1. Evaluate the 1st header expression
2. Evaluate the 2nd header expression; if true goto 3., else goto 6.
3. Evaluate the body of the loop
4. Evaluate the 3rd header expression
5. goto 2.
6. Exit

If you know how while-loops work, this might help you:

```c
for (A; B; C)
    BODY
```

is similar to

```c
A

while (B) {
    BODY

    C
}
```

So in the case of your code, when you only hit the enter key, the body of the loop runs once (for `'\n'`) and prints `0`. When you enter `a`, the body of the loop runs twice (for both `'a'` and `'\n'`) and the output is thusly `01`.

Note: Your code should probably look something more like this, using modern C style:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{   
    for (int nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; nc++)
        printf("%d", nc);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ohhhh, true, I missed this detail, i get it now, thank you! The empty for loop confused me a lot, i will remember not to use it, phew.

Comment: @carylex You're welcome! Was it the for-loop evaluation order that tripped you up?

Comment: The usage of empty for loop tripped me, i never used it, this was the first time...